# Eslint error on logical nullish assignment

Tags: javascript, eslint

The code is like this

```
const a = { dur: 50 };
a.speed ?? = 25;
```

eslint 8.19.0 says

```
2:12  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =
```

"npx eslint . --fix" didn't fix anything.

Any suggestions pls ?

Comment: What ECMA version is set in ESLint?

Comment: yes change to 2022 fixed the issue, thx

Comment: Seems like a bug still IMO - they should show it's not allowed if some setting is off, not show a parser error.  Their customization system leaves a lot to be desired as you can't see what to do until you get stuck and waste 5 hours googling stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between `??` and `=`. Those characters must be together to be parsed as a single operator.

```
a.speed ??= 25;
```

In addition, ensure that a high enough ECMAScript version is set in `.eslintrc.json`.

```json
{
    "parserOptions" : {
        "ecmaVersion": 2022
    }
}
```

Comment: same lint error

Comment: @user3552178 Try editing `.eslintrc.json` to add: `"parserOptions":{"ecmaVersion": 2022}`